# How do you join two data.tables on column(s), Y, while conditioning on other column(s), X

Tags: r, join, data.table, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have two data.tables DT1 contains {ID,LAB_DT,A1c} and DT2 contains {ID,LAB_DT}

DT1[, LAB_DT] is a time-dependent date by ID and DT2[, LAB_DT] is a time-independent date by ID.

```
DT <- data.table::data.table(ID=c("a","a","b"),
                 LAB_DT=c("2002-01-02","2002-01-03","2002-01-01"),
                 A1c=c(8,6,6))
DT2 <- data.table::data.table(ID=c("a","a","b"),
                  LAB_DT=c("2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01"))

DT[,LAB_DT:=lubridate::as_date(LAB_DT)] 
DT2[,LAB_DT:=lubridate::as_date(LAB_DT)]
```

I ideally want to join these two tables so that any ID in DT with an A1c <7 and whose DT[, LAB_DT] > than DT2[, LAB_DT] remains after the join.

I know that joining data.tables looks something of the sorts like:

```
DT1[DT2, on=.(ID,LAB_DT)],
```

I don't know how to condition on columns that are not referenced in the "on" argument; however, I tried the below but found out that's not the correct way to go about it:

```
DT1[DT2 & DT1$A1c <7 & (DT$LAB_DT > DT2$LAB_DT), on=.(ID,LAB_DT)]
```

> Error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

The end results should be:

```
   ID     LAB_DT A1c
1:  a 2002-01-03   6
```

Has anyone successfully joined two data.tables while using non-referenced columns in the "on" argument as conditions? I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: @Jaap what does the nomatch arguement do in this case? Also, how will the code differ if LAB_DT in DT2 is instead C.2A_DT?

Comment: it removes the case where there is no match for the non-equi-join part `LAB_DT > LAB_DT`; try the code without th `nomatch`-argument and you'll see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
DT[A1c < 7
   ][unique(DT2)
     , on = .(ID, LAB_DT > LAB_DT)
     , nomatch = 0
     , .(ID, LAB_DT = x.LAB_DT, A1c)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    ID     LAB_DT A1c
> 1:  a 2002-01-03   6
> ```